# undefined method `has_many' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Now able to Test `has_many` relations in rspec

Error:

```
Failures:

  1) Account associations
     Failure/Error: it { should has_many :account_members}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_many' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Account::Associations:0x007feaac7ea470>
     # ./spec/models/account_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**spec/models/account_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Account, type: :model do

  context "valid Factory" do
    it "has a valid factory" do
      expect(build(:account)).to be_valid
    end
  end

  context "associations" do
    it { should belong_to :creator }
    it { should has_many :members }
  end

  context "validations" do
    before { create(:account) }

    context "presence" do
      it { should validate_presence_of :name }
    end
  end

end
```

**spec/factories/accounts.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    name {Faker::Company.name}

    association :creator
  end

end
```

**app/model/account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  acts_as_paranoid

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :created_by_id
  has_many :invitations
  has_many :members, class_name: "AccountMember"

  # validations
  validates :name, presence: true

  # Methods

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    name_changed?
    end

end
```

Comment: It is futile to test ActiveRecord methods, because they are already tested

Comment: `rspec-rails` doesn't provide such matchers. You can install `shoulda-matchers` gem to get those.

Comment: I have added it in `rails_helper.rb` - require "shoulda/matchers"

Comment: @Nermin didnt get you. please can you explain

Comment: Can you try `have_many` instead of `has_many`?

Comment: Every association that is provided with ActiveRecord, such as `has_many`, `belongs_to`, are already well tested by their makers, it is not recommended for you to test that again

Comment: @Nermin you mean Rails will throw up errors and no need to be tested using rspec?

Comment: @Pavan `have_many` is for having more records.

Comment: Yes. That's what should be used when you have `has_many` association

Comment: @Pavan damn!! got it :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `shoulda-matchers`, then it should be `have_many` not `has_many`.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Account, type: :model do

  context "valid Factory" do
    it "has a valid factory" do
      expect(build(:account)).to be_valid
    end
  end

  context "associations" do
    it { should belong_to :creator }
    it { should have_many :members } #here
  end

  context "validations" do
    before { create(:account) }

    context "presence" do
      it { should validate_presence_of :name }
    end
  end

end
```

Refer to this [***Documentation***](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames) for more Info.